# FluentNhibernate not creating an Id column as an identity with SQL CE 4.0

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-ce, integration-testing

I have am trying to create some integration tests with no external database dependencies so am using SQL CE 4.0 and trying to configure it with FluentNhibernate.

I have gotten so far as having the tests create the database file each time it runs, then create the table that i want to use but it never sets the Id column to and identity specification. When i then try and insert into the table with Nhibernate it complains about a null identity column.

This is my mapping defenition and data class:

```
public class AffiliateApplicationRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string DomainName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }

    public AffiliateApplicationRecord()
    {
        DateReceived = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class AffiliateApplicationRecordMap : ClassMap<AffiliateApplicationRecord>
{
    public AffiliateApplicationRecordMap()
    {
        Table("Partner");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.CompanyName, "Name");
        Map(x => x.DomainName, "Domain");
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.DateReceived, "TimeStampCreated");
    }
}
```

And these are the methods that configure the Session Factory which i call in my repositories to get a session factory to run queries/insert data.

**EDIT: Added Dialect configuration...**

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

        var config = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
                    .Dialect<MsSqlCe40Dialect>()
                    .ConnectionString("Data Source=DatabaseFileName.sdf"))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(typeof(AffiliateApplicationRecord).Assembly))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildConfiguration()

        return config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
    }
```

I'd really appreciate help with this. I am worried that either Fluent won't do this for me or that SQL CE won't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the SQLCe toolbox i realised that the table was being created with an identity column correctly and that the problem i was seeing (AssertionFailure: “null identifier”) was actually caused by a bug in SQL CE described here...

[AssertionFailure: "null identifier" - FluentNH + SQLServerCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361730/assertionfailure-null-identifier-fluentnh-sqlserverce)

Many Thanks SO

Answer (score 0):

try using the  MsSqlCe40Dialect instead of the MsSqlCeDialect.

Comment: Didn't seem to make any difference, please see edited question to see if i have done this correctly